# transparent text with shadow in CSS

Tags: html, css

how to make text in CSS like this [image: this]

.as you can see, text is transparent and it has shadow. i tried text-shadow property with color:transparent but it doesn't give the right result

Comment: How did that site do it?  An image?  I don't believe what you want to do is possible because the full shadow sits behind the text, therefore if the text is fully transparent you'll simply see the shadow.  In the image above the transparent text actually cuts into the shadow, something that doesn't appear possible via css, but maybe someone can prove me wrong.